# How can I stop a pyftpdlib FTP server?

Tags: python, multithreading

I just got started with pyftpdlib . What I want to do first is take the example server and wrap it in a thread. but if i run this the script just won't exit:

```
from pyftpdlib.authorizers import DummyAuthorizer
from pyftpdlib.handlers import FTPHandler
from pyftpdlib.servers import FTPServer
import logging

import threading

class FtpThread(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, user_list):
    self.user_list = user_list
    self.killswitch = 0
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
  def run(self,*args,**kwargs):
    authorizer = DummyAuthorizer()
    authorizer.add_user('user', 'bla', '/home/user/git/verteilerCore2/default_basedir/in/1/', perm='elradfmwM')
    handler = FTPHandler
    handler.authorizer = authorizer

    logging.basicConfig(filename='/var/log/verteiler_ftp.log', level=logging.INFO)
    handler.banner = "pyftpdlib based ftpd ready."
    address = ('', 21)
    self.server = FTPServer(address, handler)
    self.server.max_cons = 256
    self.server.max_cons_per_ip = 5
    self.server.serve_forever()

  def stop(self):
    self.server.close_all()

def main():
  ftp_server = FtpThread("")
  ftp_server.start()
  import time
  time.sleep(1)
  ftp_server.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What do I have to do to make server_forever stop? calling "close_all" stops the server from serving, but the whole script won't exit :(

Comment: "stops the server from serving" - does that mean it will not accept any further requests?

Comment: yes. i cannot connect. but the thread does not exit.

Answer (score 2):

I bumped into the same issue (python 2.7.14, Ubuntu 16.04). As suggested in https://github.com/giampaolo/pyftpdlib/blob/master/pyftpdlib/test/test_servers.py, I got it working by using ThreadedFTPServer iso FTPServer.

```
from pyftpdlib.authorizers import DummyAuthorizer
from pyftpdlib.handlers import FTPHandler
from pyftpdlib.servers import ThreadedFTPServer

import threading

def __init__(self, addr):
    authorizer = DummyAuthorizer()
    authorizer.add_anonymous(os.getcwd())

    handler = FTPHandler
    handler.authorizer = authorizer
    handler.banner = "pyftpdlib based ftpd ready."

    ThreadedFTPServer.__init__(self, addr, handler)

    # set a limit for connections
    self.max_cons = 256
    self.max_cons_per_ip = 5

def _run_server(self):
    self.serve_forever()

def start(self):
    srv = threading.Thread(target=self._run_server)
    srv.deamon = True
    srv.start()

def stop(self):
    self.close_all()
```

--> in this case, calling "close_all" exits the script

Comment: Note, it's only documented at lower levels, but "addr" needs to be a tuple, in python2 this was not the case, but the library may blow up in bind_af_unspecified() trying to parse a string if you passed "217.0.0.1" as the address, and omitted the port number 21 in a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Tried that on windows 8 and it does exit cleanly:

```
[I 14-10-28 11:49:18] >>> starting FTP server on :::21, pid=1892 <<<
[I 14-10-28 11:49:18] poller: <class 'pyftpdlib.ioloop.Select'>
[I 14-10-28 11:49:18] masquerade (NAT) address: None
[I 14-10-28 11:49:18] passive ports: None
[I 14-10-28 11:49:19] >>> shutting down FTP server (0 active fds) <<<
```

Can you provide more details about your setup?

Comment: i'm running debian 7, python 2.7 and the current version of pyftpdlib. thanks for your help.

Comment: I've tried that on Ubuntu and it does stuck, I've looked deeper in the pyftpdlib's source code and there's a test which implements exactly what you need and doesn't get stuck https://code.google.com/p/pyftpdlib/source/browse/trunk/test/test_ftpd.py (line #240)

Comment: i saw these test classes before, but i can't make out why my code shouldn't work. i'd rather find the problem than copy so much code. thanks though

Answer (score 0):

If found this solution. Tested on Windows 10 and Linux (Windows 10 WSL).

```py
from pyftpdlib.authorizers import DummyAuthorizer
from pyftpdlib.handlers import FTPHandler
from pyftpdlib.servers import ThreadedFTPServer
import os


class MyFTPHandler(FTPHandler):
    def on_file_received(self, file):
        if os.path.basename(file) == 'last_file':
            self.server.close_when_done()


def main():
    authorizer = DummyAuthorizer()
    authorizer.add_anonymous('/mnt/c/Temp/ftp' if os.name == 'posix' else r'C:\Temp\ftp', perm='w')

    handler = MyFTPHandler
    handler.authorizer = authorizer

    server = ThreadedFTPServer(('0.0.0.0', 21), handler)
    server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```